# serializedObject becomes null bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Custom Editor, I subscribed to the `EditorApplication.update` event to do some stuff every frame with my object:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyCustom))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects()]
public class MyCustomEditor : Editor
{
    private bool is_subcribed = false;

    void MyUpdate()
    {

        if (serializedObject == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("serialized object is null");
        }

        // My code stuff
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        if(!is_subcribed)
        {
            EditorApplication.update += MyUpdate;
            is_subcribed = true;
        }
    }

}
```

It works great, but if I go to a **Prefab** of my parent object (that **does not have** this CustomEditor), choose its **child object(s)** that **has** this **Custom Editor** attached and **while they are selected** I exit out of **Prefab Mode** seems like `MyUpdate` function continues to call itself and ( since those **child object(s)** are not selected and the `serializibleObject`  is gone) throwing this madness into my console:

[image]

I have tried to implement some try/catch thing and unsubscribe from `EditorApplication.update` but I am new to C#, so I failed :( Can someone help me to impement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't remove the listener. So the next time the `EditorApplication.update` is called you already "destroyed" the editor instance the `MyUpdate` callback points to so it will be `null`.

The error doesn't happen because `serializedObject` would be `null` but the callback entry (your `MyCustomEditor` instance)
 in `EditorApplocation.update` itself is `null`.

---

To remove the callback just use the same line but with a `-=` instead.

Note: It is also allways "save"/allowed to remove a listener even if it doesn't exist yet. So I would do

```
// This is called when the object gains focus
private void OnEnable()
{
    // This makes sure the callback is added only once
    EditorApplication.update -= MyUpdate;
    EditorApplication.update += MyUpdate;
}

// This is called when the object loses focus or the Inspector is closed
private void OnDisable ()
{
    EditorApplication.update -= MyUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@derHugo is right with his answer but the problem is that `OnDisable` is called after `MyUpdate` so I see error message once. It's not critical but I still impemented try/catch just to keep console more clear:

```
void OrbUpdate()
{
    try
    {
        MyCustom = (MyCustom)serializedObject.targetObject;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Catching that bug :(
    }

}

private void OnDisable ()
{
    // And then unsubscribing
    EditorApplication.update -= MyUpdate;
}
```